# React Native JSON Array as Parameter to LINQ Contains

Tags: arrays, entity-framework, linq, react-native, fetch

I want to get a list of people that have the same tags as the user.
For that I need to use a react native fetch and the entity framework.
I also tried some raw sql with EF, but couldn't make it work, just don't know how.

I have two fetches. Both return a typical JSON object array. So I'm doing this:

```
var users = db.Users
.Include("TagUsers")
.Where(u => u.TagUsuario.Any(t => tags.Contains(t.idTag))).ToList();
```

The tags variable is an object array from a React Native Fetch, which in my C# function is of the type `IList<>long`.

The problem is that if this array have one element, like this `const tags = [1];` or from the fetch like this

```
{0}
Tags:
idTag: 1
Name: "MyTag"
```

I can return the people with this tag, but if I do like this `const tags = [1, 2];` or

```
{0}
  Tags:
    idTag: 1
    Name: "MyTag"
{1}
  Tags:
    idTag: 2
    Name: "AnotherTag"
```

It returns nothing on my LINQ request.

But if I do something like this on my C# function:

```
IList<>long tags = new List<>long();
tags.Add(1);
tags.Add(2);
```

It works perfectly.

The problem here is that the object array from the fetch is not "compatible" with the LINQ statement (Any, Contains). So I am in search of an alternative.

What do I have to do?
Change the IList parameter? I'm using that because accepts null without crashing.
Change the LINQ?
Use Raw SQL?
Maybe some conversion to get only an int array with the tags, not an object one.

Thanks for any tips and solutions.

Comment: Can you project `tags` into an array? For example `tags.Select(t => t.idTag)`

Comment: try calling "AsEnumerable()" on the IList

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to get the idTags from tags and use it as below.

```
var idTags = tags.Select(t => t.idTag);
var users = db.Users
              .Include("TagUsers")
              .Where(u => u.TagUsuario.Any(t => idTags.Contains(t.idTag))).ToList();
```